# Connecting Git repository Via Jenkins throwing Permission Denied Error

Tags: jenkins

[image]

While connecting Git Repository using SSH key, I am getting

stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh8082731096055760363.sh-copy': Permission denied
fatal: unable to fork.

Please help solve the issue.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726018/jenkins-checkout-of-git-project-fails-with-permission-denied-fatal-unable-to-fo) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins checkout of GIT project fails with Permission denied fatal: unable to fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726018/jenkins-checkout-of-git-project-fails-with-permission-denied-fatal-unable-to-fo)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked to me in Ubuntu:

- Find all file systems with `findmnt` in order to look what options you have in `/tmp` folder. check if there is a option named `noexec`.
- Open `/etc/fstab` and modify add a new configuracion for `/tmp` where **noexec** is listed. e.g `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs exec 0 0`.
- `mount -a` to mount all file system mentioned in `fstab`.

If you are using a version in Ubuntu higher than **20** then follow the answer  found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061265/tmp-in-tmpfs-how-do-this-only-with-systemd/1061328#1061328)